# Probability calculation by Proc means T-test

Tags: statistics, sas, k-means, p-value

I need to calculate P-values linked to these t-values will reflect the probability that they are equal to 0 by using PROC Means for each visit. Also I have only one classifying (i,e Treatment group=1). Alpha for this test is set to 0.05.

Following code is what I am using, but I am not getting desired p-value?

```
PROC MEANS DATA=< input dataset>ALPHA=0.05;
    BY _VISNAME;
    VAR Total_Score;
    OUTPUT OUT=D1<output dataset>
            N=
            MEAN=
            MEDIAN=
            STD=
            STDERR=
            UCLM=
            LCLM=
            PROBT= / AUTONAME;
RUN;
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your data set, so I can only guess at question. For starters, I would put your descriptive statistical keywords into the top line next to `data=`. This should at least generate some form of result:

```
proc means data=work.sample N MEAN  MEDIAN  STD  STDERR  UCLM LCLM PROBT T;
BY _VISNAME;
VAR Total_Score;            
output out=work.means; 

run;
```

Comment: sorry i can't share data-sets here, but thanks for your quick reply. i can share my detailed code. also i want to ask is it required t show T-value along with P-value.As i am starter for statistics, i would like to ask you how this t-value is associated with p-value generated by proc means. please find my code below:

Comment: Nope, you don't need to show t-values (T) with p-values (PROBT). I just added them on because I thought you might need to use them since you had mentioned t-values on the question. Did the code generate anything?

Comment: code is generating p-values correctly. i was bit confused as we have only one treatment group in a study and so amazed how and what p-values signify here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think p-values were something to do with probability and distributions. It's been a while since I last took a stats class. Usually experiments have only 1 control group and 1 to n number of treatment groups. But if the answer helped, please accept it. Cheers.

Comment: Here in my case i have only one group, do i have to show P-value for both Visit(Baseline) Mean and Change from baseline(following visits) or just for change values?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's a statistics/probability question, so you should be able to ask on Cross Validated.

Comment: @ved_null_ ...Soo did my answer help you?